# Can't find method java.util.Timer.schedule with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, smartfoxserver

I'm programming a JavaScript app

in the app there is a button when the user clicks on it, a door supposed to be opened for 7 seconds then close again

that's my code :

```
if (cmd == "clickOnButton") {
  var rVars = []
  rVars.push({
    name: "door",
    val: 1
  }) // 1 for opening , 0 for closing

  _server.setRoomVariables(r, user, rVars)

  function closethedoor() {

    var rVars = []
    rVars.push({
      name: "door",
      val: 0
    })
    _server.setRoomVariables(r, user, rVars)
  }
  setTimeout(closethedoor, 7000);
}
```

the door open successfully but it doesn't close after 7 seconds , that's the problem I found:

> Can't find method java.util.Timer.schedule(adapter1,org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined).

Using smart fox server pro

Comment: Dupe of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63759761/settimeout-doesnt-work-in-javascript-app

Comment: for us `_server.setRoomVariables(r, user, rVars)` comes from nowhere, looks like an Alien attack.

Comment: Some stuff at their site https://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1048

Comment: @mplungjan I have already read it before asking here, but didn't understand how to do it
could u please help me with it depending of above code?